# Splitting suit from card

Tags: java, regex

So basically I have to split the card from the suit, my code is almost working, but always the last suit doesn't split from the card. My code so far:

```
String userInput = input.nextLine();
String[] allCards = userInput.split("[SHDC](\\s+|$)");
```

So lets say the input is: `2H 3D 5C KS KH`

The output is: `2 3 5 K KH`

I'm stuck, please help.

Comment: Please try and format your answer better. I cannot tell what it code and what is not.

Comment: Ye sorry about that, gonna try and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input doesn't contains white space in the end , so try to replace `\\s+` with `\\s*`  it could help :

```
"[SHDC]\\s*"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your code splits only when the suit name is followed by one or more spaces. Change your regex to enable the end-of-line marker to follow the suit's character, like this:

```
[SHDC](\\s+|$)
```

Here is how it works with your input string:

```
String[] tt = "2H 3D 5C KS KH".split("[SHDC](\\s+|$)");
for (String s : tt) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/MCiqp9)